# Castor custom collection field handler

Tags: java, collections, xml-serialization, castor

I'd like to unmarshal the following xml to a [MultiKeyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html):

```
<map>
    <entry key1="foo" key2="foo">
        <value property="val"/>
    </entry>
    <entry key1="bar" key2="bar">
        <value property="val"/>
    </entry>
</map>
```

I took a look through the Castor API and saw that there's a [CollectionFieldHandler](http://www.castor.org/1.2/javadoc/org/exolab/castor/xml/handlers/CollectionFieldHandler.html) class, but I can't find any documentation on where I would need to register a custom collection handler.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, collection isn't a map.

You can implement and register your own handler.
See http://www.castor.org/xml-fieldhandlers.html